# How to connect to an Excel workbook that lives in SharePoint 2013 and update it

Tags: c#, excel, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I am creating a command line application and I would like to connect to a SharePoint site that has a workbook that I want to update.

I don't even know where to start but I guess the questions I have are.

- What API can I use for this? It has to be something that is already built-in and not a third party API if possible :)
- Once the connection is done and I am able to open the spreadsheet, will I be able to also switch from one sheet to another?

I've tried to use some code like this but it did not work.

```
    private static void GetExcelSheetNames(string filename)
    {
        var xls = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        xls.Visible = true;
        xls.DisplayAlerts = false;
        var workbook = xls.Workbooks.Open(Filename: filename, IgnoreReadOnlyRecommended: true, ReadOnly: false);
        try
        {
            // Refresh the data from data connections
            workbook.RefreshAll();
            // Wait for the refresh occurs - *wish there was a better way than this.
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
            // Save the workbook back again
            workbook.SaveAs(Filename: filename);  // This is when the Exception is thrown
            // Close the workbook
            workbook.Close(SaveChanges: false);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Exception message is "Cannot save as that name. Document was opened as read-only."
        }
        finally
        {

            xls.Application.Quit();
            xls = null;
        }
    }
```

The Exception that I get was:

Microsoft Excel cannot access the file 'https//url/bla/bla/bla/workbook.xlsx There are several possible reasons:

- The file name or path does not exist.
- The file is being used by another program.
- The workbook you are trying to save has the same name as a currently open workbook.

Actually, it seems like it is trying to open an instance of Excel Desktop in my machine.

Sorry for such an open question but I don't really know how can I connect to a SharePoint site.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a document in a document library, check to make sure that it is checking out the document before you try to save it.  I am working with a similar process but using a report library instead of a document library and am able to save documents without check out/in.